# get the typename of a class template

Tags: java, generics

I want to get the typename of a class template (ex set). for example when i use :

```
Set<Personne> p = new HashSet<Personne>();
/* manipulate p etc ... */
```

How can I know the typename of p (which is Personne) using something like `p.getTypeName()` even if p is empty.

Comment: Java has generics, but not templates like in C++. So `HashSet` is not a "class template". Generics in Java do not work in the same was as templates in C++.

Answer (score 6):

At runtime, you can't. This is due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: not at runtime ? i want just to test if the generic type is equals to Personne or not

Comment: @ChrisCashwell - That's going to be false, since `p` points to a `HashSet`, not a `Personne`.

Comment: @ChrisCashwell p is a set of elements, how can it be an instance of Personne ? One element of p maybe an instance of Personne (and may not be since it can be just a type like int)

Comment: @ChrisCashwell he also precise that he wanna know that "even if p is empty", so how you gonna do it in this case ?

Comment: @user995434 If you have an empty set, why would it matter what parameter was passed? I should have been more clear. Comments redacted.

Comment: @ChrisCashwell suppose you have locally a set A of objects of type SomeType and another set B of objects of type SomeOtherType. Suppose you receive a set of objects of type T, if this set is empty and T is SomeType, you want to empty (clear) the set A. How would you do that if there is not indicator in each object telling you that it is of type SomeType or SomeOtherType ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the parameterized type at runtime because of Java's type erasure. If, however, you know what types it *might* be and just want to check if it is one of those:

```
if (someObject instanceof SomeType) {
    ...
} else if (someObject instanceof SomeOtherType) {
    ...
} ...
```

Comment: However, even if you know what types it might be, suppose you have a set of some objects that are of some type, I guess you can not test if the type is of SomeType or SomeOtherType when the set is empty, right ?

Comment: @user995434 If you have an empty set, why would it matter what parameter was passed?

Comment: suppose you have locally a set A of objects of type SomeType and another set B of objects of type SomeOtherType. Suppose I reserve a set of objects of type T, if this set is empty and T is SomeType, I want to empty (clear) the set A. How would you do that if there is not indicator in each object telling you that it is of type SomeType or SomeOtherType ? @ChrisCashwell